# JBoss Wildfly 10: xnio ClassCastException when calling EJB3.1 on JBoss 7

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jndi, rmi

I'm trying to remote call an EJB3.1 application on a JBoss 7 from a Wildfly 10 via JNDI.

Executing the code from a stand alone java client works perfectly well, deployed in the Wildfly, I receive a ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.xnio.SingleOption cannot be cast to org.xnio.Option
```

Here are the properties I'm using:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=true
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=some.server
remote.connection.default.port=4647
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=true
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.clusters=ejbremote.cluster.ejb.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.cluster.ejb.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=true
remote.connection.default.username=user
remote.connection.default.password=password
org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context=true
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
```

Project has the jboss-as-ejb-client-bom dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Lookup looks standard:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
Service service = (Service) ctx.lookup(Service.JNDI_PATH);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you completely remove the `jboss-as-ejb-client-bom` dependency?

Comment: Standard "No EJBReceiver available error message" :/

Comment: What you are doing here does not look anything like what the documentation describes at [EJB invocations from a remote server instance](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance)

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I'm trying to call a service which is deployed on different servers and I have to be able to specify the exact server on which the service should be called on (and no, use case is not self implemented load balancing ;)), which, as far as I know, is not possible when following the linked implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Add an jboss-deployment-structure.xml with the following contents to the top level of your WAR:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.jboss.xnio"></module>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The xnio dependencies are part of the jboss-as-ejb-client-bom. I checked the versions, and the wildfly uses the 3.4.0.Final of xnio, the ejb client bom uses them in 3.0.7.Final. I now tried the following things: 1) added the jboss-deployment-structure.xml like you suggested to the WEB-INF of my war file. No effect. Read a few things about deployment structure, 2) tried to add the module as an exclusion in the deployment structure (I suppose wildfly uses it's local version of xnio instead of the packaged one?), didn't work either.

Comment: 3) What I also did: Excluded xnio entirely from the dependency: Get the classic "No EJB Receiver available" error message when making the service call. 4) Excluded xnio but added it afterwards explicitly in the same version wildfly uses: Again, ClassCastException.

Comment: I suppose you use AS7.
In that case you have to set a dependency to the "org.xno module."
See [Class Loading in AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7)

Comment: Client application is deployed on wildfly 10, server application on JBoss 7, yes. Added the org.jboss.xnio module  as a dependency in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml of my client application, still receive the ClassCastException.

Comment: Can you check this WAR doesn't have any other version of the xnio libraries present. They shouldn't conflict but if you are including API libs in your WAR this may cause class-loading issues.  Refer the link describes the JBoss class loading [Class Loading in AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7)

Comment: mvn dependency tree shows me that only the mentioned ejb-client dependency has the xnio dependencies. If I exclude these explicitly, the war file doesn't contain any xnio libraries at all. Just to be really precise: I have a jar module, which has the ejb-client dependency and thus receives the xnio dependency transitively. My war module which produces the war-file has a dependency on my jar module. I specified the jboss-deployment-structure.xml in my war module and it ends up being packaged in the war-file under WEB-INF/classes/. Is all of this correct? Thanks a lot for your help anyways!

Comment: In the meantime: Not only added the dependency to xnio in my deployment, but also specified a sub-deployment for my jar with the dependency. Still, ClassCastExceptions.

Comment: I believe your WAR must have had a dependency to another xnio library that it was using. I didn't check as I didn't have the deployment itself so I just thought I would ask you to try it. I can't be certain about the dependency in your WAR but if the jboss-deployment-structure.xml solved it then it was more than likely the cause.

The dependency make sure the correct modules are loaded by the classloader. With the exception of jboss-javaee-6.0 and jboss-as-ejb-client-bom, these dependencies must be added to the <dependencies> section of the pom.xml file.

Comment: Included with the JBoss EAP Maven repository is a dependency management BOM, which specifies all supported JBoss EAP binary artifacts. This BOM can be used in a build to ensure that Maven will prioritize supported JBoss EAP dependencies for all direct and transitive dependencies in the build. In other words, transitive dependencies will be managed to the correct supported dependency version where applicable. The version of this BOM matches the version of the JBoss EAP release.

Comment: The client BOMs do not create a dependency management section or define dependencies. Instead, they are an aggregate of other BOMs and are used to package the set of dependencies necessary for a remote client use case.

Comment: Sorry, for this endless discussion. Okay, obviously, I used the BOM entirely wrong. So I now moved the BOM to my DependencyManagement section. I basically used the set up described [here](https://github.com/PiotrNowicki/jboss7-remote-ejb-client/blob/master/pom.xml). This is how my pom for my jar-project looks like. Now I still have the deployment-structure.xml in my war-project which defines a dependency to org.jboss.xnio. In my war file, the xnio-api is packaged under /WEB-INF/lib/. I still receive ClassCastExceptions.

Comment: "org.jboss.xnio" is a PUBLIC module of JBoss EAP means shipped with JBoss eap distribution. Use the default  module provided by JBoss. Remove our custom module from /WEB-INF/lib/ folder. I damned sure these jars are conflicting which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

check how you package the application, I suppose that you include the org.xnio libraries in the deployed archives.
In this case it will be loaded by different classloaders that cause this error.